# Is 'column-adding' (schema modification) a key advantage of a NoSQL (mongodb) database over a RDBMS like MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, database, nosql

I recently went to a tech talk sponsored by 10gen on NoSQL/MongoDB. I'm not a DBA superguru or anything, and the speaker made an interesting point intended to illustrate one of the strengths of using a NoSQL database.

The example was this:
Craigslist is using MySQL. They have a huge table with millions, maybe hundreds of millions of records. They need to modify the schema of this table by adding a column to it. Since there are so many records in this table, actually adding the column takes *3 months*

He goes further to say that with a NoSQL database, you don't have to do anything - just start saving objects to a collection with that extra property you want to record.

I get this, maybe it takes a while to modify a huge dataset with an RDBMS engine. But is this really a huge downside of an RDBMS? Was this an exaggeration? Can such an operation be sped up?

Comment: No it is not an exaggeration...trust me....

Comment: The speaker wants to sell a product, so he is likely exaggerating with his 3-month estimate. But he is right when he says that the flexibility for schema changes is a big strength of document-oriented databases (but note that this doesn't apply to all those technologies which are often grouped under the catch-all label of NoSQL).

Comment: @Philipp, my thoughts too. What kind of time-frame is this really more like? I'm actually considering whipping up a test DB, populating it with as many records as possible, and trying this

Comment: You will need a distributed envo with at least 100 shards and maybe upto a couple of billion records with high accession. I am unsure if you can just "spin up" a test. Even then you probably still won't get to the point of where other companies are at when they say this kind of stuff

Comment: I don't get. He is assuming it is OK not to add the column to the older records ?

Answer (score 4):

I would be highly skeptical of that 3 month time frame. I've worked with MySQL tables before with hundreds of millions of rows, and even on hardware from years ago, adding a column might take at most a few days, not months. Of course this varies by the amount of data contained in each row, but I'd still be skeptical.

Of course just extending the table using an ALTER TABLE is probably not the best way to go...it's usually much faster to create a new table from the old one (CREATE TABLE [new table] LIKE [old table]), alter the schema on the empty table, copy all the rows from the old table to the new table, (INSERT INTO [new table] SELECT [fields] FROM [old table]), then rename the new to the old.

Comment: I think 100's of millions of rows is a bad thing for the OP to say because SQL is easy to handle at say 500 million. It is when you start branching out into truly large enterprise solutions that changing the schema starts to really hit hard

Answer (score 3):

There's not many good solutions for schema flexibility in the RDBMS world. It usually revolves around storing xml/json or twisted database design. It works, but it's really awkard and it can eventually wreck your whole application (maintenance or performance wise). This is especially true when you have a lot of data.

Regarding Craiglist, their ads are just a bunch of different aggregates without interactions between them. Instead of bending their RDBMS, they chose a document oriented database. It makes sense when you think about it : they don't really care about consistency (in the ACID context). Giving that up, they gain high scalability, flexible schema and ease of use. The bottom line is : the real strength of RDBMS is integrity and consistency, not schema flexibility.